# execute multiple lines in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am a newbie with both python and jupyter notebook.

After searching I found that if I wanted to execute multiple lines for sqlContext I had to use triple """ like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("""select year,month,count(distinct station) as count
               from tempReadingsTable
               where year>=1950 and year<=2014 and value>=10
               group by year,month
               order by count desc
                """).show()
```

Now, I am trying to find the same for this:

```
schMax = schMax.groupBy('year').
agg(fun.max('value').alias('value')).
join(sch['year','value']).
drop_duplicates(['year']).
select(['year','station','value']).
orderBy(['value'],ascending=[0])
```

Unless I run it all in one line it fails! how can I prevent that? I want to be able to execute all the lines separately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\` at the end of a line to have python continue reading the next line as part of the previous line (removing white spaces if needed).
Although I think it's more readable if you put the `.` on the start of each new line. It's more apparent that it's part of the previous statement since normal statements never begin with `.` in python.

```py
 schMax = schMax.groupBy('year')\
                .agg(fun.max('value').alias('value'))\
                .join(sch['year','value'])\
                .drop_duplicates(['year'])\
                .select(['year','station','value'])\
                .orderBy(['value'],ascending=[0])
```